# Determine reverse order of data given X/Y coordinates

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine an electrical connector. It has pins. Each pin has a corresponding X/Y location in space. I am trying to figure out how to mirror, or 'flip' each pin on the connector given their X/Y coordinate. note:  I am using pandas version 23.4 [image: Rough Paint Sketch Visual] We can assume that x,y, and pin are not unique but connector is. Connectors can be any size, so two rows of 5, 3 rows of 6, etc.

```
x    y    pin   connector
1    1     A       1
2    1     B       1
3    1     C       1
1    2     D       1
2    2     E       1
3    2     F       1  
1    1     A       2
2    1     B       2
3    1     C       2
1    2     D       2
2    2     E       2
3    2     F       2
```

The dataframe column, 'flip', is the solution I am trying to get to. Notice the pins that would be in the same row are now in reverse order.

```
x    y    pin    flip   connector
1    1     A       C        1
2    1     B       B        1
3    1     C       A        1
1    2     D       F        1
2    2     E       E        1
3    2     F       D        1  
1    1     A       C        2
2    1     B       B        2
3    1     C       A        2
1    2     D       F        2
2    2     E       E        2
3    2     F       D        2
```

Comment: I have the feeling that I saw this question yesterday.

Comment: @QuangHoang yes I deleted it and attempted to make it more thorough/clear.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: What's wrong with the answers yesterday?

Comment: @QuangHoang the answers were removed as they did not address the whole problem (my fault).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC try using `[::-1]` a reversing element and `groupby` with `transform`:

```
df['flip'] = df.groupby(['connector','y'])['pin'].transform(lambda x: x[::-1])
```

Output:

```
    x  y pin  connector flip
0   1  1   A          1    C
1   2  1   B          1    B
2   3  1   C          1    A
3   1  2   D          1    F
4   2  2   E          1    E
5   3  2   F          1    D
6   1  1   A          2    C
7   2  1   B          2    B
8   3  1   C          2    A
9   1  2   D          2    F
10  2  2   E          2    E
11  3  2   F          2    D
```

Comment: I believe this may do the trick, I want to play around with it a little bit more.

Answer (score 1):

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = """
x    y    pin   connector
1    1     A       1
2    1     B       1
3    1     C       1
1    2     D       1
2    2     E       1
3    2     F       1
1    1     A       2
2    1     B       2
3    1     C       2
1    2     D       2
2    2     E       2
3    2     F       2
"""

#strip blank lines at the beginning and end
data = data.strip()

#make it quack like a file
data_file = io.StringIO(data)

#read data from a "wsv" file (whitespace separated values)
df = pd.read_csv(data_file, sep='\s+')
```

Make the new column:

```
flipped = []

for name, group in df.groupby(['connector','y']):
    flipped.extend(group.loc[::-1,'pin'])

df = df.assign(flip=flipped)

df
```

Final DataFrame:

```
    x   y   pin     connector   flip
0   1   1   A       1           C
1   2   1   B       1           B
2   3   1   C       1           A
3   1   2   D       1           F
4   2   2   E       1           E
5   3   2   F       1           D
6   1   1   A       2           C
7   2   1   B       2           B
8   3   1   C       2           A
9   1   2   D       2           F
10  2   2   E       2           E
11  3   2   F       2           D
```

Comment: I think `flipped.extend(group.loc[::-1,'x'])` is populating the 'flip' column with 'x' values instead of 'pin'.

Comment: @MaxB Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map between the original coordinates and the coordinates of the 'flipped' component. Then you can select the flipped values.

```
import numpy as np

midpoint = 2

coordinates_of_flipped = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df['x'].map(lambda x: x - midpoint  * np.sign(x - midpoint )), df['y'], df['connector']])

df['flipped'] = df.set_index(['x', 'y', 'connector']).loc[coordinates_of_flipped].reset_index()['pin']
```

which gives

```
Out[30]: 
    x  y pin  connector flipped
0   1  1   A          1       C
1   2  1   B          1       B
2   3  1   C          1       A
3   1  2   D          1       F
4   2  2   E          1       E
5   3  2   F          1       D
6   1  1   A          2       C
7   2  1   B          2       B
8   3  1   C          2       A
9   1  2   D          2       F
10  2  2   E          2       E
11  3  2   F          2       D
```